# How to implement ASP.NET Web API Authentication by username/Password & ClientID/ClientSecret

Tags: security, asp.net-web-api

My Web API serve 2 different category of consumer.
1. Actual end-user that login with ID and Password.
2. Another application that integrate with my application via the API.

What is the best practice when implementing the Authentication and Authorization for such a system?

I have two solution here:

[image: Using the same Web API project for both web app and API]

Figure 1. Using the same Web API project for both web app and API

[image: Using different Web API project for web app and API separately.]

Figure 2. Using different Web API project for web app and API separately.

The solution in Figure 2 is more straight forward to implement the authentication layer. But it might have duplicate APIs endpoint in both project (although most of the business logic is contain in Service layer).

What is the best solution here?
If Figure 1 is the better solution, then how can i implement the authorization layer? Any library that can achieve that?
Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

for you Authentication and Authorization , you can use identity and Owin in asp.net

check this link for Authentication and Authorization

http://johnatten.com/2014/10/26/asp-net-web-api-and-identity-2-0-customizing-identity-models-and-implementing-role-based-authorization/

or
http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/

or you can try to generate token using guid();